# How to globally optimize an ODE?

Tags: optimization, curve-fitting, ode, model-fitting, shgo

Consider the following ODE

[image]

and the following datasets

[image]

How can I find α and β that best fit this data?

**My approach:** As an example, consider the following data

```
x1 = np.array([91., 110., 125., 105., 88., 84.]) 
x2 = np.array([1.0, 0.97, 1.0, 0.95, 0.92, 0.8])
```

at time points

```
t_list = np.array([0, 5, 9, 18, 28, 38])
```

Using a [numerical approach](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) (see [Python script here](https://justpaste.it/edit/59288380/mc054bi18wz2e9mq)), and a polynomial regression of `x1`, I get the following fit

[image]

with α ≃ 0.000486, β ≃ 0.057717, and a [chi-square error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test) of 0.0017296. However, this is highly dependent on the initial guesses for α and β. Is it possible to use a global optimizer to improve this? I have tried [`shgo`](https://%CE%B1%20%E2%89%83%200.000486,%20%CE%B2), but I always get a worse fit (higher chi-square). Any ideas?

Comment: For your model, what is the variation of x wrt t?